# Messed up my path in Zsh?

Tags: macos, bash, zsh

I'm trying out zsh as an alternative to bash, and I seem to have messed up my system path on my MacBook Air. Here's the path I have in my `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Some commands like `vim` work properly, but standards like `ls` and `sed` are returning errors like the following:

```
zsh: command not found: ls
```

I'm pretty sure it's not just a zsh problem, as launching a bash terminal produces similar results.

It seems like I'm missing an important directory in there somewhere. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin`

there is a `/` missing in-front of `usr/bin`

so it should be

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: hi, I try your answer and it works, but after I re-open the terminal, it happens again, and getting ```zsh command not found``` is there a way to solve this